# White Patching Over UV Unwrap

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: White Patching]

Can anyone tell me what the white triangles are in the image on the left after a UV Unwrap please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that two faces are superpose ; which doesn't seem to be true in your case. The issue is some of your faces are Ngons (they have more than 4 vertices), and 2.8 UV editor acts weirdly with concave Ngons.

As far as I know, you can safely ignore it, it shouldn't cause any issue.